# Hybrid_property with marshmallow

Tags: python, properties, sqlalchemy, hybrid, marshmallow

I have the following code:

```
markers = db.relationship("Marker", back_populates="track")


    @hybrid_property
    def first_marker(self):
        if (len(self.markers) > 0) is True:
            return self.markers[0]
        return None
```

and using marshmallow to serialize it. But when I run the app, it raises an error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'InstrumentedAttribute' has no len()
```

What I want is this hybrid property to return the first element of the markers list.
It looks like when I start the app, marshmallow is calling this function with self.markers as the "Relationship" object, but why?
How could I fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It'll help if you can narrow down the code to a [smaller example](http://sscce.org/), showing the marshmallow schema and the exception traceback.

Comment: I found the issue. My marshmallow Schema was:
fields = (
            Track.first_marker.key,
        )
but it should have been
fields = (
            "first_marker",
        )

Thank you for your help.